# mat cap not showing up

Tags: 3d-view, interface, edit-mode, shaders

I can't find the mat cap under the shadings panel, does anyone know why?I can find it just fine on my other projects, but not on this one.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Just change the view port shading to solid.